# Whats the best way to clean this wheel up?

Tags: motorcycle, automatic-transmission, paint-scratches

I purchased this wheel on ebay because I was instructed it was balanced, but needed to be cleaned. The seller told me it was a mix of body filler from the orange-red,chrome still on it and the black looks like paint and the gray is some sandable primer. I know that the effect it puts off looks a lot like a paint stripper that I have put on walls before, sound like he tried removing it before selling it, but sol it as is.

Comment: Repeated coats of paint stripper should do it.

Comment: Chemicals + elbow grease + time = clean wheel.

Comment: One other option is sand blasting, youtube has some videos on making a homemade one which will just about do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chemicals and Elbow grease did the trick, ty.